# What are the reasons that make platinum a good electrocatalyst for oxygen reduction reaction?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, catalysis

Researchers are trying to find new electrocatalysts for energy related reactions in fuel cells in order to replace the expensive platinum-based materials.

I would like to know what are exactly the properties of platinum that make it have such a good performance (1 step reduction reaction of oxygen/4 electron process)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: related? : https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34145/platinum-group-metals-why-are-platinum-and-palladium-great-catalysts-and-not-th?rq=1